# Integrate Cognitive Speech in Directline 4.0 Webchat

Tags: botframework, speech-recognition

[image]Previously in `V3.0` I was using this code and passing it to `Bot.App` as parameter, but I don't know how to achieve this in Directline `V4.0` using `Webchat-E5.js`

```
const speechOptions = {
        speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({ locale: 'de-DE', subscriptionKey: '1add78901d9d' }),
        speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer({
            gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
            subscriptionKey: '1add78125a901d9d',
            voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (de-DE, Stefan, Apollo)'
        })
    };
```

Many Thanks in Advance.

Text to Speech not working with Cognitive Bing API.

```
 window.fetch('https://sfbotspeech.cognitiveservices.azure.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken', { method: 'POST', headers: {
                            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : 'f9d649bf33bf2427c', 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' , 'Content-Length': '0'} })
         .then(function (res) {
          return res.text();
        })        
        .then(function (authtok) {
              SpeechToken =  authtok;

        console.log(SpeechToken)    ;
        const webSpeechPonyfillFactory =  WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
           authorizationToken: SpeechToken
         });

        ///
        WebChat.renderWebChat(
            {
                bot: bot,
                directLine: WebChat.createDirectLine({token}),
                user: user,
                //speechOptions: speechOptions,
                resize: 'detect',
                styleOptions: styleOptions,
                selectVoice: (activity) =>
                    activity.locale === 'de-DE',
                webSpeechPonyfillFactory : webSpeechPonyfillFactory
            },
            document.getElementById('BotChatGoesHere')          
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the solution but I am getting error of 401 . I am not sure what url to use for the token, I have registered Bing Speech on Azure as a global resource. I used the Subscription to authenticate but still its shows unauthorized.

Comment: Did you look over the other BotFramework-WebChat samples? There are Bing Speech samples available. You should know that Bing Speech requires a different setup than Cognitive Services Speech so you should take the time to research what’s available and will provide a solution.

Comment: Actually I integerated the old one with Cognitive one the same Bing Speech. I tried to find the solution but its not authorizing

Comment: Did you try sample [06.a.cognitive-services-bing-speech-js](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.a.cognitive-services-bing-speech-js)? I would suggest trying it without any customizations or modifications and just aim on getting it working. Also, you should know that Bing Speech is deprecated. Consider switching to Cognitive Services Speech.

Comment: Yes I carried out the same thing, without any customization, simply just passing. webSpeechPonyfillFactory with access token. Access token is generating successfully. Please check uploaded image in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out sample [06.g.select-voice](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.g.select-voice) located on the BotFramework-WebChat repo. The attached `index.html` shows the complete code.

The above sample expands on sample [06.c.cognitive-services-speech-services-js](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.c.cognitive-services-speech-services-js). If you need additional guidance, consider looking this one over.

Hope of help!

Comment: Please note that I am using Webchat-es5.js

Comment: 2list:1 GET https://westus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/voices/list net::ERR_ABORTED 401

Comment: window.fetch('https://fbotspeech.cognitiveservices.azure.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken', { method: 'POST', headers: {
       'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : '1add75a901d9d', 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' , 'Content-Length': '0'} })
  .then(function (r) {
     SpeechToken =  r.text();

Comment: ES5, noted. Can you edit your original post and place the code you have in your comment into there? Then it’ll be formatted and readable.